# how to change pom.xml version from jenkins and push to git branch

Tags: git, jenkins

presently we are changing pom versions manually from cmd prompt and commiting to git branch.

i want to configure this version change in jenkins

i want to do automatically change the pom.xml version from jenkins once it is successfull. i want to push it to remote git branch from jenkins.
we are using the command **mvn version:set -Dnewversion=1.0.0** to change the pom version
can any one tell me how to configure this command in jenkins and push to remote git branch automatically with out manual interaction

Comment: You can certainly configure a maven release build in jenkins. Will that work for you?

Comment: you mean maven release plugin we need to install in jenkins server?

Comment: I can have a look on my jenkins server on Monday and write the details, if it helps you..

Comment: Ok, firstly, are you going from `-SNAPSHOT` versions to release version? E.g. from `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.0.0`? If thats the case then you can use the jenkins Build Environment: *Maven release build* configuration. Otherwise you just use the jenkins Build: *Goals and options*. Regarding your branch, will it always be the same branch? Or are you creating multiple different branches in git.